# Associate two different variables in a cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Let's say I have a cell `c_infos` <1x313 cell>, that contains (among others) a name associated to a `node_ID`. `c_infos{1,i}.node_ID` and `c_infos{1,i}.name`. I want to create a matrix that for each `node_ID`, we do have all the associated names.

I started with:

```
function [] = displayNodeCusts (c_infos)
list = [] ;
for i = 1:length(c_infos)
    for j = 1:length(c_infos)
        if c_infos{1,i}.node_ID == c_infos{1,j}.node_ID
            list(end+1) = c_infos{1,j}.name
        end
    end
end
end
```

But then I don't know which node is associated to the names.

Comment: If each `c_infos{1,i}` is a struct with the same fields, use a struct array instead of a cell array of structs. `s_infos(i).node_ID` and `s_infos(i).name`. This will be a lot more efficient in storage, and also more convenient to work with. Even better is to use `table`. You should use `cell` only for heterogeneous collections or objects that cannot be arrayed by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called *cellfun* which will perform the same task in all of the cells within your variable. By doing this, you can pull out all of the names without having to use for loops. I wrote some code as an example. Hope this helps.

```
listofnames = cellfun(@(x) x.name,c_infos,'UniformOutput',false);

uniquefromlist = unique(listofnames);

for aa = 1:length(uniquefromlist)
    allrelevantentries = strcmp(uniquefromlist{aa},listofnames);
    storage{aa} = {c_infos{allrelevantentries}};
end
```

Comment: `cellfun` is a loop. Your code and OP's code both have two loops

Comment: noted. I shall update the answer once I get a chance. After rereading the post, I don't think I answered the question. Just changed the code